# STLにはなぜグラフが用意されていないのですか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

STLには木構造を持つものは用意されていますが、C++でグラフを利用したいのですが、mapなどの木を持つ構造からグラフ化することはできますか。

Comment: ここでいう「グラフ」とは、グラフ理論の「グラフ」でしょうか？
それとも描画の「グラフ」でしょうか？

Comment: アルゴリズムのグラフ理論の方になります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduction to Algorithms(アルゴリズムイントロダクションの１巻）を読むと答えに近づけます。

http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4764904063

グラフの表現方法がいくつかあり、一言で「グラフ」というデータ構造を表すものは定義できないと思います。

代表的なものだと次の２つでしょうか。

- 隣接リスト
- 接続行列

なので、

> STLにはなぜグラフが用意されていないのですか？

という質問に対しては、「これがグラフだ！」という一般的なデータ構造が決められないから　というのでどうでしょうか？（ハイパーグラフとか出てくるとさらに大変なことになりそう）

> グラフ化することはできますか

という質問に対しての解は、「STLを用いてグラフを表現することはできます」という感じでどうでしょうか。